# What do warnings C4247 and C4248 mean and why were they removed from Visual C++ 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

According to MSDN, Visual C++ 2003 and Visual C++ 6 could emit [warning C4247](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984123%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> 'member' not accessible because 'class1' uses 'access' to inherit from 'class2'

and [warning C4248](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984124%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> 'class1' : cannot access 'access' 'member' declared in class 'class2'

There's no information on these warnings and they are no longer emitted in newer versions (2005 and above).

What did they mean and why were they removed?

Comment: Those sound like they should be errors, not warnings.

Comment: According to the link, 4247 is a warning rather than an error because it occurred due to a type cast.  Not sure why 4248 isn't an error.

Comment: @K-ballo: They're in fact errors nowadays (VS2010 at least), accidentily discovered that recently.

Comment: Why do you say there is no information on them when you have hyperlinked to more information some rows above?

Comment: @phresnel: I meant "no information except the above stuff".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These were replaced by errors:

- [C2247](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1ktd2d9.aspx):  'identifier' not accessible because 'class' uses 'specifier' to inherit from 'class'
- [C2248](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh.aspx):  'member' : cannot access 'access' member declared in class 'class'

Note that aside from the first digit, the error numbers are the same as the old warning numbers.  For the most part, C++ errors start with '2', Managed C++ and C++/CLI errors start with '3', and warnings start with '4'.

Comment: I don't get one thing - why were they not errors from the very beginning?

Comment: Because Visual C++ has been around for a very long time, and many parts of C++ have changed over time, especially during the C++98 standardization process.